# the element is selected from drop-down menu but not from jQuery

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium and Java to write a test. Somewhere in the DOM we have this select:

```
<select name="operator" id="jsonform-20577-elt-operator" required=""> 
    <option value="<"> < </option> 
    <option value="<="> <= </option> 
    <option value="="> = </option> 
    <option value=">"> > </option> 
    <option value=">="> >= </option>  
</select>
```

When I use:

```
WebElement element= wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(
                    "//select[@name='operator']")));

action.sendKeys(element, "<=").build().perform();
```

it selects <= from the drop-down menu but when we check the select value from jQuery, we see that it's not changed (it has the previous value).

but if I add a `keys.ENTER`:

```
action.sendKeys(element, "<=",keys.ENTER).build().perform();
```

it works. why didn't it work without enter? why was it selected from drop-down box, but later in other parts of the application it still had the previous value?

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: why didn't it work without enter? why was it selected from drop-down box, but later in other parts of the application it still had the previous value?

Answer (score 0):

Using `sendKeys()` to the dropdown doesn't select the option, only type the text. Selenium has the [Select](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html) class to handle dropdowns selection

```
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//select[@name='operator']")));
Select select = new Select(element);

// select by text
select.selectByVisibleText("<=");
// or select by value
select.selectByValue("<=");
```

Note that this will work only on `<select>` tags.